# sonarqube gradle plugin excluding jacoco integration tests

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradlew

I'm trying to integrate the sonarqube gradle plugin with the jacoco plugin:

classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.1'

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

My build/jacoco folder contains:
integrationTest.exec
test.exec

However, the sonarqube plugin only recognises the 'test.exec' file:

18:20:45.130 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: C:\Users\abc3\Downloads\sme-letter\target\jacoco-it.exec
:
18:05:55.609 INFO  - Analysing C:\Users\abc3\Downloads\sme-letter\build\jacoco\test.exec

How do I get the sonarqube plugin to recognise 'integrationTest.exec'

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Is 'build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec' something standard? I was not aware of a built in support of integration tests in Gradle. Would you mind sharing a sample project in SonarQube user group? If this is something standard we could improve the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle to support it out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure, whether this will work for Gradle plugun, but you may try.

Sonar has a property to specify the name of the integration tests JaCoCo report. This property is called `sonar.jacoco.itReportPath` (`sonar.jacoco.reportPath` for unit tests report).

And as far as I know, gradle sonar plugin let you add custom properties to it. So you can change IT report name via properties as follows:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "build/jacoco/ integrationTest.exec"
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle only consider the "unit test" coverage report.

Comment: So is there any way we can add "it report" coverage report. It was working with maven, it shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but only after merging all jacoco reports into one file AND (important) deleting all other reports

```
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "$projectDir/build/test-results"
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths', "${rootProject.buildDir}/jacoco/mergeJacoco.exec"
```

And you need a merge jacoco task

```
Task mergeJacoco = tasks.create('mergeJacoco', JacocoMerge, {
  doFirst {
      delete "$buildDir/jacoco/mergeJacoco.exec"
  }
  destinationFile(new File(buildDir, 'jacoco/mergeJacoco.exec'))
  executionData fileTree('./').include('**/*.exec-partial')
  doLast {
      delete fileTree('./').include('**/test.exec-partial')
  }
})

mergeJacoco.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
project.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn mergeJacoco
mergeJacoco.mustRunAfter ":myProject:test"
```

And setup jacoco to use those "partial" files

```
subprojects {
    ....
    jacoco {
        destinationFile file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec-partial")
        append = false
        includes = ['com.mypackage.*']
    }
}
```

You'll get unit and IT reports mixed in one, but that's the best I could get